# Would L' Hospital's Rule be applied to the following limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

How would I go about showing that:

$\lim_{p \to \infty} (|x_{1} - y_{1}|^{p} + |x_{2} - y_{2}|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}} =$ max $\{|x_{1} - y_{1}|, |x_{2} - y_{2}|\}$

I was considering L' Hospitals Rule, but I am not sure if that would get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital won't help, I think, but you could use the [sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Set $a:= x_1-y_1$ and $b:=x_2-y_2$

Without loss of generality assume $\left|a\right|\ge |b|$. 
Now
$$\left|a\right| = \left(\left|a\right|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\left|a\right|^p+\left|b\right|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(2\left|a\right|^p\right)^{1/p} =2^{1/p}\left|a\right|\stackrel{p\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \left|a\right|$$

Thus $\left(\left|a\right|^p+\left|b\right|^p\right)^{1/p}$ tends to $\left|a\right|$ as well.

Comment: So the idea here is that you just supposed that $|x_{1} - y_{1}|$ was in fact the max. How did you get the following part: $(2|a|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Comment: @user121895 if $|a| \ge |b|$ then $|a|^p\ge|b|^p$ thus $|a|^p+|b|^p\ge 2\cdot |a|^p$

Comment: I dont think thats true. What if $a = 3$ and $b = 2$. Then, $9 + 4$ is not greater then $2 \cdot 9$.

Comment: Of course that was a type. should be $\le 2|a|^p$ as I have written in my answer. In the answer it is correct.

Comment: I gotcha. Thanks.